# I want to know if this error is due to library duplication

Tags: android, jar, java-native-interface, aar

There are two libraries in my app.

One is an encryption library (A), and one is a virtual keypad library (B).

I use the A library directly,

also virtual keypad library uses A internally and is included in the aar.

B only uses 2 of A's functions and only 2 functions are visible when converted to Dex Jar. (BA Function, BB Function)

However, when I build my app, I get a function-related error that is not called from B.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method BC()
[B in class Lcom/Encryption/Encrypt/API; or its super classes
 (declaration of 'com.Encryption.Encrypt.API'
 appears in /data/app/kr.co.MyApp-1/base.apk:classes8.dex)
```

Is this related to having only 2 functions when converting B to Dex Jar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, seems so. It can happen because a single version of a library is chosen when here are a dependencies duplication, and the biggest version is chosen for building apk, e.g. imagine that your application uses "super-log:log:2.0" directly, as well as "super-downloader:downloader:1.0.", which, in it's own context, uses "super-log:log:1.0". So, during building gradle seeks for duplicates and chooses biggest version of them to include in the build, in our case it is" super-log 2.0". So, apk was created successfully, but in runtime, if here is an interface mismatch between "superlog 1.0" and "superlog 2.0", error will occur (it depends which one exactly, but usually it is NoSuchMethodError related to ClassDefNotFoundError (the same effect can be achieved with raw java: just compile two classes, when class A depends on class B, invoking one of B's functions, and after compilation just delete B.class and ClassDefNotFoundError will occur)).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I can not change the current structure. When call all the functions of A in B, Could the problem be solved?

Comment: @ilikecat, if here are some particular modules that library B is using from the older version of library A, you can try to exclude this module from direct dependency declaration of A in your module's build.gradle. But it is impossible to determine how the system will behave after that due to A's unique architecture. If it will solve the previous NoSuchMethodError case, then proper testing required to make sure that nothing else that uses A got broken. You can see how it can be done here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#managing_transitive_dependencies

Comment: I'll try. Thank you. :D